# Making KnockOut observable array property observable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, knockout.js

I have a observable array  `AllItems` defined as

```
var ViewModel = function () { 
  var self = this; 
  self.AllItems = ko.observableArray([]);
}
```

It gets filled by data from a ajax call and I just add the properties received from the Ajax call directly to the array without defining them.

I am using it in the below HTML to populate a table.

```js
var ViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.AllItems = ko.observableArray([]);
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.1/knockout-min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: AllItems">
    <td>
      <span>$</span><span data-bind="text: $data.RequestedPrice"></span>
    </td>

    <!-- ko ifnot: (Number(RequestedPrice) > Number(ItemDetails.SmPrice))  -->
    <input type="button" disabled value="Approve" id="Approved" data-bind="click: $root.ApproveItem" style="background-color:#e1eae5 !important" />
    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- ko ifnot: (Number(RequestedPrice) > Number(ItemDetails.SmPrice))  -->
    <input type="button" disabled value="Approve" id="Approved" data-bind="click: $root.ApproveItem" style="background-color:#e1eae5 !important" />
    <!-- /ko -->

    <nobr>$
      <input type="text" class="priceChange" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" style="display:inline !important" data-bind="value: $data.RequestedPrice" />
    </nobr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

SO i have three things in the above HTML. First I am just displaying the text of the requested price. Second I am using it to disable a button and third I am making it a editable field.

The issue is that when I change the value it is not reflected in the text and also the second case where it is used to disable a button is not updated. Can someone please tell me what I need to achieve this.

Comment: Please add all viewmodel parts which you use in the bindings in the HTML. Also add mock data.

Comment: Why do you have the exact same button twice? Also, fix your HTML structure, it is completely invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Three options:

- Write a custom mapping from your js(on) coming from the back end to objects that do have observable properties;
- Use [ko.mapping](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html);
- Use [knockout.es5](https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout-es5) with some custom code;

Knockout, as oppossed to Angular 1, requires you by default to be explicit about which stuff you want to be observable (when using ko.mapping you're explicitly saying all the stuff is observable).